# UK Postcode and London destination

Tags: shapefile, data, united-kingdom, postal-code

New to this site... I'm working with Postcode regions in the UK and was wondering if anyone know if there is a dataset which give you postcode region and the most likely station destination within London...

i.e.  - LE - Leicester - St.Pancras / Kingscross

Comment: I'm not sure if this data set exists. By 'most likely' do you mean the station the least traveling-time or the station most travelers go to? These may not necessarily be the same.

Comment: There is a little bit of information at the National Rail Enquiry developer site. Check out the developer pack. [http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/static/documents/themanual/NRE_Feeds_Developer_Packv01-02.pdf] They seem to want to embrace open data so contacting them might be a good idea. Nice question !

Comment: Link above does not seem to work - leaves on the track?. Anyhow if you search for National Rail Developer you will find it.

Comment: If it's open data you are after then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange may be the place for this question.

Comment: use Meridian2 it has stations info you will need to cross-reference with your postcodes https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/meridian2.html#Specifications